# Can I query the Facebook API and see a list of all of my Facebook App payments (not using Real-time payments)?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql, facebook-c#-sdk, facebook-apps

Is there a way to query the Facebook API using the Javascript or C# SDK or FQL to show all of my app payments.  I know there is a way to query for a specific user or query a specific transaction id.  The Real-time payments log is an option but I would love a second option that I can use just in case the real-time payments piece is not working on my side for whatever reason.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As alternative, there are daily [Payment Reports](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/developer_reports_api/).